# Why is .mock.instances printing this?

Tags: jestjs

This code snippet is pulled from the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-property).

```js
const myMock = jest.fn();

const a = new myMock();
const b = {};
const bound = myMock.bind(b);
bound();

console.log(myMock.mock.instances);
// > [ <a>, <b> ]
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the
`console.log(myMock.mock.instances)` prints:

`[< a >, < b > ]`

I'm just a little confused why tags are being printed.

In addition, when I run it on my machine I get:

`[ mockConstructor {}, {} ]`

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` and `<b>` aren't tags but formatting for special values that differ from regular JavaScript values.

`[<a>, <b>]` means that `myMock` function received `a` as `this` on the first call and  `b` on the second call.